# Compose 'Placeholder" text

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

This is going to be hard to explain in text but I will try. I have the following text field:

```
 OutlinedTextField(
            modifier = modifier ...
            label = { Text("Amount") },
            value = value.toString() , // as an Int parameter
            onValueChange = updateAmount, // callback

            placeholder = {
                Text( "0") <-- problematic line
            }
        )
```

What happens is that as the user first clicks on the text field and starts typing, the placeholder text disappears and is replaced by the input text as expected.
However, if you press `backspace` until the typed text is all gone, it is replaced with zero again, but this time, the cursor is ***before*** the placeholder text, so it becomes part of the typed text.

Example for clarification:

```
 --------
| 0|     |   <- placeholder text and cursor
 --------

 --------
| 1|    |   <- input text
 --------
 --------
| 12|    | 
 --------
 --------
| 123|    | 
 --------
Now deleting:
 --------
| 12|    |   
 --------
 --------
| 1|    |   
 --------
 --------
| |0    |   
 --------

Now typing again:
 --------
| 1|0    |   
 --------
 --------
| 12|0    |   
 --------
```

Effectively the placeholder text is becoming part of the input.

Is this a bug or a feature ? And how to work around this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm fairly sure it doesn't work that way. The placeholder doesn't, *can't* become part of the value. Those composables aren't even connected. Perhaps you have logic somewhere else that replaces an empty value with `"0"`?

Comment: I just figured it out after completely removing the placeholder, and being confused for 5 more minutes. Thanks anyway, that was exactly what was going on.

Comment: ` _amount.value = newAmount.toIntOrNull() ?: 0 `

this is the faulty function. I will try to work around this now. Thanks.

Comment: @Jorn If you add that as a short answer I would mark it as accepted. Also if you have any best practices tip concerning this that would be welcome as well.

Comment: Added! I'm not sure what kind of advice you are looking for. In this case, I think it's fine to have `_amount` be a `MutableState<Int?>` instead of non-nullable, so you can detect the difference between an explicit `0` input and `no input`. You can then handle defaulting to `0` in the business logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placeholder doesn't, can't become part of the value. Those Composables aren't even connected. I think you may have logic somewhere else that replaces an empty value with 0, perhaps when parsing the text input to an `Int`.